# When a file is uploaded to a website, can the website see the file path it's uploaded from?

Tags: javascript, php, html

When uploading a file, before pressing the upload button, the folder/file path is visible in the website's upload form.

[image: upload form].

Is the website able to record that data?

Normally a website could possibly record any data typed into a web form - is this any different?

Comment: what do you mean by website in "can the website see the file path it's uploaded from"? and your question is not clear that what you want.

Comment: No. Browsers never puts full path but rather just the filename ,may be in older browser there was some way to see the full path using`file.path` property but in modern browsers that property is faked using something like `C:\fakepath\yourfile.ext`

Comment: What is that? post a link

Comment: @Raunak: Hmm... the question is very clear to me, did the uploaded file come from c:\something\somefile.txt oder from c:\Users\Alice\Desktop\somefile.txt? I never thought of that, interesting question!

Comment: RaunakGupta sounds like a good quesion to me, did you even tryed to understand it? @Robert Agreed, very interesting question, would like to know the answer too !

Comment: As fas as I know the path of the original file is not sent at all. Chrome and IE replace the path info with "C:\fakepath\" Firefox doesn't supply any path at all.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to work. I created the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5samkn5a/

Basically I took an input

```
<input type="file" id="input"/>
```

And set a listener to its value

```
$(function(){
$("#input").change(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
})
})
```

Then I tried it in the latest chrome/firefox/edge
They all give a fake path as value. The only thing that's real is the file name. May be that some browsers actually expose the full path, but not the ones I tested.

It makes sense that the browser is shielding this information since at least on windows when you are choosing a document it will most likely reside in your current user directory. So the path will contain your local user name and that's not something you want to give to a random website, right?